# Error al exportar reporte a pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Tengo un error al momento de exportar un reporte a `pdf` estoy usando `Jasper Report 5.6.0` antes el reporte me lo exportaba bien pero ahora no lo quiere hacer y en el log no tengo ningún error este es el código para imprimir

```
    public void PDF() throws JRException, IOException {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("plantaPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select s from ticket s where s.id='" + ticketID + "'");
    List<ticket> listTicket = (List<ticket>) query.getResultList();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listTicket);
    String reportPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/reports/report1.jasper");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath, new HashMap(), beanCollectionDataSource);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
    httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream;
    servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

}
```

y así lo llamo desde la pagina

```
  <p:commandButton value="Imprimir" action="#{verTicketController.PDF()}"/>
```

Comment: Creo que deberías quitar la actión ajax de tu botón o usar `<h:commandButon>` en su lugar.

Comment: si luiggi ya lo solucione y efectivamente el boton de primefaces no funciona para exportar un jasper tube que usar el boton de jsf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás escribiendo el contenido de la respuesta del servidor para descargar un archivo. El botón de PrimeFaces, por defecto, siempre dispara una acción ajax, y por naturaleza (y seguridad) de los navegadores, no se pueden descargar archivos mediante ajax.

Tienes dos alternativas para resolver el problema:

1. Agregar `ajax="false"` en tu `<p:commandButton>` para deshabilitar la funcionalidad ajax y que puedas descargar el archivo.
2. Usar `<h:commandButton>` de JSF que no provee ajax.

Comment: es cierto lo que comentas muchas gracias buen punto para los que comienzan con jasper y primefaces le debe suceder lo mismo ya saben que hacer.